# cmake - set default command line options

Tags: cmake

I would like that when I run cmake for a certain CMakeLists.txt the "--warn-uninitialized" and "--warn-unused-vars" options are automatically turned on without actually typing those options.

How could I do that?

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to create an alias:

```
alias mycmake='cmake --warn-uninitialized --warn-unused-vars'
```